# Image exists but i get an error Init:ErrImageNeverPull Container image is not present with pull policy of Never

Tags: docker, kubernetes, k3s, containerd

I am deploying an app on **k3s with containerd** (not docker)
am trying to deploy a local image
the image **exists** but the given error
said **image doesn't**

```
docker.io/kubernetesui/metrics-scraper            v1.0.8              115053965e86b       19.7MB

**docker.io/library/laravel-example-project-fpm     latest**            ac83c8e9c86fd       378MB

docker.io/library/laravel-example-project-nginx   latest              6403f5d7120c6       24.2MB
rn-manager             v1.1.0              6a6ea3dbf71b9       116MB
docker.io/monachus/rancher-demo                   latest              65053fcc5f37a       7.01MB
docker.io/rancher/klipper-lb                      v0.3.5              dbd43b6716a08       3.33MB
docker.io/rancher/local-path-provisioner          v0.0.21             fb9b574e03c34       11.4MB
docker.io/rancher/mirrored-coredns-coredns        1.9.1               99376d8f35e0a       14.1MB
docker.io/rancher/mirrored-library-traefik        2.6.2               72463d8000a35       30.3MB
docker.io/rancher/mirrored-metrics-server         v0.5.2              f73640fb50619       26MB
docker.io/rancher/mirrored-pause                  3.6                 6270bb605e12e       301kB
root@u-server-master:~#
```

---

```
kubectl describe pod laravel-example-project-5597cdcc97-bv6fs
```

---

```
kubectl describe pod laravel-example-project-5597cdcc97-bv6fs
```

---

```
Events:
  Type     Reason             Age                    From               Message
  ----     ------             ----                   ----               -------
  Normal   Scheduled          45m                    default-scheduler  Successfully assigned default/laravel-example-project-5597cdcc97-bv6fs to zakham
  Warning  Failed             42m (x12 over 45m)     kubelet            Error: ErrImageNeverPull
  Warning  ErrImageNeverPull  4m57s (x187 over 45m)  kubelet            Container image "**laravel-example-project-fpm:latest**" is not present with pull policy of Never
```

---

```
kubectl get pods

laravel-example-project-5597cdcc97-26scj........ 0/2...........**Init:ErrImageNeverPull**.......0................ 26m
```

**SOLVED**
i am using a local image with containerd i dont need to pull it, i solved it by specifing the node name nodeName because i noticed that when the pod is scheduled to the master node it run without error, so i specified that nodeName in the deployment

Comment: Can you try changing the pull policy to `Always` and see if it makes difference?

Comment: i am using a local image with containerd i dont need to pull it, i solved it by specifing the node name nodeName because i noticed that when the pod is scheduled to the master node it run without error, so i specified that nodeName in the deployment

Comment: i have the same scenario as you, check the latest answer, take care.

Answer (score 0):

You get this error because the image is never pulled to the node, and you are using a never [imagePullPolicy](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/containers/images/#image-pull-policy), which means that K8S will not pull the image if it doesn't exist or if there is a new version on the docker registry.

To solve this problem, you can use imagePullPolicy `IfNotPresent` to pull the image if it doesn't exist or `Always` to pull the image at every pod creation.

Comment: i am using a local image with containerd i dont need to pull it, i solved it by specifing the node name nodeName because i noticed that when the pod is scheduled to the master node it run without error, so i specified that nodeName in the deployment

Comment: am not using minikube on my laptop am using real k3s (ligtweighten Kubenetes) on two nodes and i am using Contairned not docker,. You have to google k3s and containerd to understand more

Comment: Ah ok, so as I understood, you created a K3S cluster with two nodes, then you built the image on the node which is the master of your K3S cluster, and now you assigned your pod to the master node to find the image... In this case if there is no more resources on the master, you cannot run your applications, and to solve that you have 2 options: build the image on all the nodes (you need to build it for each new node), or just push it to a docker registry (docker hub for example), then change the pull policy as I explained in my answer

Comment: i buit it in my laptop and exported it (using docker) then i imported it to containerd local registry (using the master node to do that).  so the thing i am not understanding is why it doesnt work with the other node, and what i have to do? شكرا حبيبي

Answer (score 0):

**FIRST I SOLVED it like** this i am using a local image with containerd i dont need to pull it, i solved it by specifing the node name nodeName because i noticed that when the pod is scheduled to the master node it run without error, so i specified that nodeName in the deployment

**FINALLY I SOLVED IT LIKE THIS**
i just imported my image to all workers nodes and delete that nodeName parameter from the pod and **it worked like a charm**

Answer (score 0):

Since your image is local and/or you can be using a local registry the pull policy Never is fine. Also double check if there is any valid reason to not get the image runnning on any other node.

Try to not use a nodeName unless it has for example dedicated hardware among other things. Theres a big chance to have a taint on your Master.

Check the taints on master node if you want to schedule tasks there.

I would recommend to take a look here for further info: [Taints and Tolerations](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/scheduling-eviction/taint-and-toleration/)

[Pod Priority and Preemption](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/scheduling-eviction/pod-priority-preemption/)

[Node-pressure Eviction](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/scheduling-eviction/node-pressure-eviction/)

A while ago i solved something really similar using antiaffinity, this [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=DKLMzDD3xqA&t=11s) explains perfectly how to achieve it.